# How to replace a string from a single line of a file which contain many identical line. Only that line will be modified rest will remain same

Tags: python, replace

I am working on a file i which based on user user input I have to search for a particular line out of many identical lines. In that I m trying to replace a string with another string. Please see below file structure----

```
Country number="100" name="Sri Lanka" travel="Yes" connectivety="Yes"
Country number="101" name="Zaire" travel="May" connectivety="No"
Country number="103" name="vietenam" travel="No" connectivety="Yes"
Country number="104" name="Alaska" travel="No" connectivety="Yes"
Country number="105" name="New York" travel="Yes" connectivety="Yes"
```

Here suppose if user give country number as <104>. We will search for that country number and for that country number we have to change { travel="No" to travel="Yes" }
Mean after replace file will be like below:

```
Country number="100" name="Sri Lanka" travel="Yes" connectivety="Yes"
Country number="101" name="Zaire" travel="May" connectivety="No"
Country number="103" name="vietenam" travel="No" connectivety="Yes"
***Country number="104" name="Alaska" travel="Yes" connectivety="Yes"***
Country number="105" name="New York" travel="Yes" connectivety="Yes"
```

Check the line present between ***.

I have written a dummy code for this...

```
mandatory = 'travel="yes"'
for line in fileinput.input(test.txt", inplace=True):
    match = re.findall('Country number="104".*, line)
    if match:
       for part in line.split():
            if 'mandatory=' in part:
                part.replace(i,mandatory)
                " ".join(part)
```

Here with this code whole file is getting removed.. Please explain me how to accomplish the work of replacing the string.

Comment: Well, is your file big? If so, I suggest using a database, otherwise just read the file as a string, manipulate the string then rewrite the whole file with the new string.

Comment: @brunodea Yes Its a big file, but change has to be done at specified line only not on all line as you can see that string "travel is present in every line"

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why you are using a text file for look-up instead of a database?

Comment: @Ymartin .. it not a data base file. Please consider it as normal file.